# Cordova app google OAuth2 invalid cookiePolicy

Tags: cordova, google-api, phonegap-build, google-oauth

**Case :**
Develop a iOS/Android app with [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) where you can login with a Google account using [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

**Problem:**
When launching the app on browser, `localhost:3000` I can login with my google account like normal but when I try to launch my Cordova app with `cordova run ios`   it crashes.

The error that Cordova is giving is:

[image]

Like I mentioned is that I use OAuth2, to login with your google account, the following settings I use in my app are:[image]

For some reason I think that there the problem is the oAuth2 link because the error that I'm having starts with gap.**auth2**

Comment: Did you crack this?
Now i stuck with the same problem. If you crack this please help me!

Thanks,

Comment: Hey @Jaccs, sorry to say but I didnt complete this app because i got this problem. Best you can do is to start over i guess

Answer (score 3):

In your phone , go to device's "Settings -> Safari -> Block Cookies".
There the enabled setting should be either "Always allow" or "Allow websites I visit", for Google Sign In to work

Comment: This doesn't help me.. Do you have any idea without this?